# How to get rid of this Unity blank box?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

In my unity project, I have this blank grey box, which is not clickable or draggable. How to get rid of it?

It used to be an information box for Merge Objects in Probuilder, as shown in the image 2. However I can't get rid of that. So I closed my project and reopened it. Then the box became blank and I got the console notice "Coundn't find a readme".

[image]

Comment: Try re-importing the Probuilder package

Comment: Id also suggest log a bug with unity.  in short, Id say, change scenes, or restart unity if that doesnt work

Comment: Thanks, tried changing scenes, restart unity. Won't work. Not sure how to re-import Probuilder package, can't find it in the package manager. But I tried changing layout, and it seems disappeared. Loading the old layout would bring the blank box out, though.

Comment: is that in your scene? Maybe just some leftover UI object that is now missing references to prefab/scripts ?

Comment: The blank grey box is not in the scene. It's overlaying on other editor windows.

Comment: Just tried removing then installing Probuilder and upgrading it. The blank grey box still exists.

Comment: I found that in this project, double clicking on the console's messages won't open up visual studio. Where can I file up a bug report to unity? @BugFinder

Comment: ide, report bug

Comment: Thanks! Bug has been reported. I'll update here if it's solved. @BugFinder